# Selecting all the records from table to which given number belongs to

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, range

Suppose I have following three records in my model :

```
#<Rda:0xf6e8a0c
 id: 1,
 age_group: "18-100",
 weight: "60",
 nutrient: "energy(kcal/day)",
 value: "2730",
 created_at: Sat, 15 Oct 2016 08:21:43 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sat, 15 Oct 2016 08:21:43 UTC +00:00>


#<Rda:0xf6e8a0c
 id: 2,
 age_group: "10-15",
 weight: "60",
 nutrient: "energy(kcal/day)",
 value: "2730",
 created_at: Sat, 15 Oct 2016 08:21:43 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sat, 15 Oct 2016 08:21:43 UTC +00:00>


#<Rda:0xf6e8a0c
 id: 3,
 age_group: "20-100",
 weight: "60",
 nutrient: "energy(kcal/day)",
 value: "2730",
 created_at: Sat, 15 Oct 2016 08:21:43 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sat, 15 Oct 2016 08:21:43 UTC +00:00>
```

Now, I want to get all those records in which my given value falls in a 'age_group' columns ranges. For example: suppose my age is 25 then I should get records with ids 1 & 3 from the above records because '25' falls in between '18-100' and '20-100'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might do

```
def self.foo(age)
  all.select { |rda| Range.new(*rda.age_group.split('-').map(&:to_i)).cover? age }
end
```

Comment: This is a nice solution.  The reason you're having trouble is that your data structure isn't normalized.  Instead of having a string "10-15" for age group, you should have 2 integer values, age_lower_bound and age_upper_bound.  Then you could do this all in Active Record.